# How can I implement the logic of both "less than" and "IN" in the filter conditions of my T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a table called `hr_employee` which contains the list of all employees in the organization. This table contains a column called "Status" and it can have only 2 values: "working" or "left". It has 2 other columns for "hired date" and "left date".

So, if I need the find total number of active employees as at a specific date (say, as at 01 July 2018), my query will look like this:

```
USE MyDatabase

select '2018-07-01' as [As At], count (*) as [CountOfEmployees] from [hr_employee]

WHERE [Status] = 'Working'

AND [left_DT] = ''

AND [hired_DT] < '2018-07-01'
```

The above query gives me the following output:

```
As At           CountOfEmployees
2018-07-01        1,550
```

My question is how to modify my existing query to get the following output (dummy figures shown):

```
As At           CountOfEmployees
2018-07-01        1,550
2018-08-01        1,200
2018-09-01        1,430
```

I am stuck at the point of hard coding the values "2018-08-01" and "2018-09-01" and implementing the logic of "less than" into my existing codes. Or am I heading in the wrong direction with this logic?

Comment: Sample data would help.  You might also want to set up a db<>fiddle of some sort.

Comment: As i understand, your business/you want know know Total Active employees as of '2019-08-01', while you pass date parameter into Function/procedure that should give total employees (this make sense), or since you already have `hired date` you may want know cumulative employee count, i think there no need of hard-coding dates, correct?

Comment: @ShekarKola I want my output to give me the total numbers of active employees as at the dates specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `values()` to list the values you want to compare:

```
select v.dte, count(e.status) as [CountOfEmployees]
from (values (convert(date, '2019-06-01')),
             (convert(date, '2019-07-01')),
             (convert(date, '2019-08-01'))
     ) v(dte) left join
     hr_employee e
     on e.hired_DT < v.dte and
        e.Status = 'Working' and
        e.left_DT = ''
group by v.dte
order by v.dte;
```

If you had longer periods of time, you might want to use a recursive CTE or numbers/calendar table to generate the values.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am the getting the following error message when running the codes: Invalid column name 'date'.

Comment: @user3115933 . . . That is a typo.